# How can I download emails for offline use with IMAP in Thunderbird and keep them after deleting them from the server?

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

As POP3 sadly [doesn't yet synchronize the read status and the folder-categorization of emails](https://superuser.com/questions/1233663/why-doesnt-pop3-synchronize-read-status-and-folders) I would like to use IMAP to download emails. After download I would like to delete them from the server but keep them locally.

How can this be done? I'm running Debian 9.1 with KDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of defeating the point of IMAP, but you’ve asked.

Thunderbird has a Local Folders section in the navigation pane on the left. Simply create a new folder in that section and drag any emails from your online mailbox into it. This should simultaneously remove them from you online box and save them locally. Recommend you make sure they are backed up somehow.