What can POP3 users do if their email provider forces a server-side spam folder on them?
I use the Thunderbird email client to receive my email via POP3 protocol from my email service provider GMX. I never needed and never used a spam filter. I have been very happy with this setup for all my life.
But now (June 2024) GMX has removed the checkbox to deselect the spam filter from its web interface, thereby forcing its server-side spam filter and spam folder on all users. (Their goal is to drive users away from email clients to the GMX mail app and/or to GMX webmail where the company can make more money with ads.)
Consequently, GMX suggests 3 "solutions" to POP3 users for this self-created problem:

use the GMX mail app instead of your email client
use the GMX webmail interface instead of your email client
use IMAP instead of POP3

So the question is: What can POP3 users do to receive the emails (including many false positives to make matters worse) which GMX now automatically moves to a separate spam folder ?

To my knowledge POP3 retrieves email only from INBOX of the mail server. All other folders are invisible to POP3. Or is there a trick or ... ANYTHING ... I can do to solve the problem using POP3 alone ?

Assuming this is impossible using POP3 alone, what is the solution if I want to solely use my email client (and not GMX's webmail or mail app) ?

I suppose I have to add an IMAP email account to Thunderbird pointing to the same email address. But how can these 2 email accounts be configured, so that first the POP3 email account downloads all emails from the GMX inbox and only in a subsequent second step the IMAP account downloads the emails from the GMX spam folder (without negatively interfering with each other) ?

The obvious solution would be to get rid of POP3 altogether and just use IMAP instead. But I don't think there is a way to configure IMAP in such a way that it behaves like POP3, or is there? My sole requirement is: Move all emails from the web server to my local storage (i.e. download emails + delete them from the web server in the same step). But I don't suppose this to be possible with IMAP. Or is it?




My preference would be (in this order):

finding a solution using POP3 alone
but if that's impossible, please tell me how to configure IMAP so that it behaves like POP3 (as described above)
and if that's also impossible, please tell me how to configure IMAP as an additional/secondary companion email account in order to retrieve the mails from the GMX spam folder in addition to the POP3 account downloading the emails from the GMX inbox. How do these 2 email accounts have to be set up in the email client (Thunderbird) so that they don't get in the way of each other ?

Thank you.

check out: https://superuser.com/questions/1243558/how-can-i-download-emails-for-offline-use-with-imap-in-thunderbird-and-keep-them

Create a second account with IMAP access, as described by the answer below. Then, through tools > message filters, create a rule in the IMAP account which will move any email to the POP3 account's inbox. You need to create a separate filter rule for any IMAP folder you wish to work on.  For safety, in the IMAP account I'd set the deletion rule to "move to thrash", so if something goes wrong emails can be recovered. This of course requires periodic deletion of the thrash, otherwise emails will remain on the server.

Create a new account in Thunderbird of type IMAP. Follow the settings pretty much like you would have done for POP3.
You may need to switch your POP3 settings to prevent deletion of collected messages. (Thunderbird does have such a switch, "Keep messages on server".)
When you're happy that all is working, move across to the IMAP account and disable the now-obsolete POP3 account. If necessary use Thunderbird to copy messages from your old POP3 mail account folder(s) to the corresponding folder(s) in your new IMAP mail account.

As a complete alternative you could use a different tool to grab the appropriate folders using IMAP. I have not investigated this for more than a few minutes, but it might be possible to adapt one of these to copy and delete much like POP3 was expected to do. These are more likely to be Linux-based than for Windows, but if you use these as a starting point you may get a useful solution.

Offline IMAP
Backup and restore IMAP mail account


Thanks, but your second sentence is the exact opposite of my stated requirement. Is this "new IMAP account" meant in addition to or instead of the existing POP3 account? Is your proposal listed in my preference #1, #2 or #3? To me it's completely unclear what you mean. If you are suggesting to get rid of POP3 entirely, please explain how to configure IMAP so that it behaves like POP3. Thank you.

Your numbered items from your question: 1. Can't be done. 2 The protocol is built around the assumption that messages remain primarily on the server. There are Linux-based tools that could help here but I know of nothing for Windows. 3. It's highly unlikely you would be able to access other mailbox folders through POP3

The protocol really doesn't care; it's built to allow messages to remain primarily on the server, but as long as it has "fetch" and "delete" operations, it can be used as if it were POP and there's nothing in its design that would prevent that – indeed fetchmail and getmail do exactly that, although neither of them can output to a Thunderbird-compatible format. (Were it not for Windows, I could think of a contrived setup where getmail mirrors to a local Dovecot IMAP server, and then you could pull from it via POP... or, in fact, use it via IMAP since by that time the data is local anyway.)
